# template class and overloading '=='

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I'm making some stack, in which I need to uses this kind of comparison in some function. But I got stuck since I don't know how the prototype for this should look like.

I have the following line in a function.

```
template <class T>
void function1(T i)
{
   if(i == 'a')
       //do something
}
```

I wonder know how the overload prototype should look like for it?

**EDIT**
Dunno if it's worth to mention, anyway this is what I have tried so far
template

```
bool Stack<T>::operator==(char c) const
{
    cout << c << endl; // just some test
}
```

No need to comment how this function works, as I have not finished it yet. This part will compile, however at the part where I call this function for the first time is in the Stack::push(T i). The compiler will complain that there are no matching function for this.

```
 error: no match for 'operator==' in 'i == '#''
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far:  I can't tell what you're asking from the question, but an example might clarify.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Your template function is fine as is when the `if` statement is completed.  But it assumes you can compare `i == 'a'`.  Is the question about how to make that possible for some type `T`, or about how to generalize that line to not use a `char` literal?

Comment: @aschepler: I want to make so I can compare type T with a character, since some point when I run this program I need to do that comparison.

Comment: Sounds like it's `T` which needs an `operator==`, so providing `Stack<T>::operator==` doesn't directly help.  So what is `T`, and can you overload for that type?

Comment: I can't figure out why you would need an operator== to implement push() -- can you show us your implementation.  My guess is that there's a syntax error that you're misinterpreting as a need for op==.

Comment: @Lou Franco, it was for making a certain output pattern. Whereas I would have one stack containing doubles, and another stack with strings. One condition is that when popping the string stack it will come back in the order you insert it, while the double stack will pop out in reverse. Furthermore user should be able to input 'a 1 b 2 c 3...' and get output 'a 3 b 2 c 1'. Here's the problem now the stack is only allowed to be 10 items big. And i'm using the string stack to keep the pattern of input contained. Thus I wanted to use ==. Anyway I've solved this problem now moving the problem out

Answer (score 1):

For overloading operators, the name of the function is `operator` followed by the actual operator, so `operator==`.  It returns bool.  I don't know what your arguments should be based on your code.  Probably `Stack<T>&`, and you need two of them to compare if it's a free function, and one to compare to this if it's a member function.

If you have ways to convert to a `Stack<T>`, then prefer a free function so that you can convert the left-hand-side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. In order for an instantiation of template function `function1` to be well-formed, you'll have to provide a `operator==` which compares a `T` and (I'll suppose) a `char`.

Now, you have two options here :

- Provide a `bool operator==(char) const` member function in your type, for example :

  ```
  struct A {
      bool operator==(char) const { /* ... */ }
  };


  function1(A()); // OK : comparison uses A::operator==(char)
  ```
- Provide `bool operator==(const T &, char)` as a free function, for example :

  ```
  struct A { /* ... */ };
  bool operator==(const A &, char) { /* ... */ }


  function1(A()); // OK : comparison uses operator==(const A &, char)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

So every T in your function1(t) has to implement operator ==;

For example, as a member function

```
class A
{
public:
   bool operator == (char) const;
};
```

or a non-member operator:

```
class A
{
public:
   friend bool operator == (const A&, char);
};
```

Comment: I have already tried that, it would give me compile error. I have edited my question with that error

Comment: It's hard to say what you actually tried, because there is no complete code fragment, so everybody just tries to guess. As it was said in this thread you need to provide operator == (member function or free) for the type T used in your function1(T i), I don't see what Stack<> has to do with it, unless variable of its type supplied to the function.